# I get my datatable. but it doesn't display

Tags: angular, primeng, angular8

im using primeng angular 8 and i get the datatable, but it doesn't display.

Here's some of my code:

**component.ts**

```
export class MedecinsComponent implements OnInit {

medecins: Medecin[];
medecin: Medecin ;
Users: User[];
cols: any[];

ngOnInit() {


this.medecinService.GetMedecins().subscribe(medecins => this.medecins = medecins);

  console.log(this.medecins);
 this.cols = [

  { field: 'Id', header: 'Id' },
  { field: 'Nom', header: 'Nom' },

  { field: 'Pays', header: 'Pays' },
  { field: 'Details', header: 'Détails'} ];
```

**medecin model.ts**

```
import { User } from './user';
export class Medecin {
 Id: number;
Details: string;}
```

**user component.ts**

```
export class User {
 Nom: string;
Pays: string;}
```

**medecin.component.html**

```
<p-dialog header="Détails de l'utilisateur" [(visible)]="displayDialog" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true" [closable]="true" [width]="600">
<div class="ui-g ui-fluid" *ngIf="medecin" >

    <div class="ui-g-4"><label for="Nom">Nom</label></div>
    <div class="ui-g-8"><input pInputText id="Nom" [(ngModel)]="medecin.Users.Nom" /></div>
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: can you create a `stackblitz` to reproduce this

Comment: We need the HTML too, the problem should be here.

Comment: ok ,i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `medecins$: Observable<Medecin[]>` and then, in your template where you currently use `medecins`, use `medecins$ | async` instead. That way, you can set `medecins$` to the HTTP call without using the `subscribe` method. It's tidier.

Also, your `Medecin` model imports `User` but does not use it. Your `Medecin` model has no `Nom` or `Pays` fields.